# FHIR Support for Approved Providers

Tags: hl7-fhir

Any recommendations on how to support approved providers for a FHIR Organization? Some of our provider organizations need to be able to request services from other provider organizations based on results of an approval process, services provided, and location.

We have to track which providers have been approved for these referring organizations. At this point, I don't think we need to be able to return the list of the approved providers as part of the requesting organizations so I was looking at the Group resource type instead of extending Organization. I don't think Group will work though because it can't include organizations, only Practitioners, and those Practitioners don't include a granular set of services provided.

Any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't reference Organization alone, you can have a PractitionerRole that only specifies the Organization and not any provider or role to signify "any Practitioner from Organization X".

The other possibility is to treat 'approval' as a qualification of the Practitioner, though that won't really help with Organizations.